# Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. It has restarted

Tags: pandas, kaggle

I was getting started with TalkingData AdTracking, my first entry to Kaggle competitions. The first line was `pd.read_csv()` and I got this error

```
Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. It has restarted
```

I thought my code was run in the cloud and that I don't have to worry about the memory requirements. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, kaggle has a memory limit: [Its 8GB per kernel, or 20 Min running.](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/31758) It takes a lot of server juice to host such a thing.

There are various solutions for this problem, notably [loading and processing the dataset in chunks.](https://www.dataquest.io/m/164-processing-dataframes-in-chunks/)

[There is this as well.](https://www.kaggle.com/gemartin/load-data-reduce-memory-usage) But I have no experience with it.

And of course you can use another cloud platform such as AWS, GCP, Oracle, etc..